# Limit animation to parent view

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell and I animate it's content out and in. But I want to limit the animation so that when the text goes outside of the UITableViewCell it's not visible in the ViewController.

The animation itself is simple:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^
     {
       yesNew.origin.x += 200;
       noNew.origin.x += 200;
       ansLblNew.origin.x = -210;

      [yesButton setFrame:yesNew];
       [noButton setFrame:noNew];
       [answerLabel setFrame:ansLblNew];

     }completion:^(BOOL finished){
       [yesButton setHidden:YES];
       [noButton setHidden:YES];
       [answerLabel setHidden:YES];
     }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting clipToBounds to YES for your cell (if you're doing it in code), or check the "Clip Subviews" check box in IB (in the "view" section of the attributes inspector).

Comment: Does not work.. I did:     cell.clipsToBounds = YES;, should I add clip to bound to each item that has should be animated aswell, well, that doesnt shoud right..

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding these subviews to your `UITableViewCell`? Are you adding them to `cell.contentView`?  If so, you should be able to set `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES`. I've experienced weird behavior in the past when I've tried to set `clipsToBounds` on the cell itself.  Alternatively, have you tried setting `myTableView.clipsToBounds=YES`?  This is untested, but it may do the trick.

Comment: Did try this aswell (both), doesnt work :/ I dont add them myself, they are added from the storyboard and I access the by tag in cellforrowatindexpath